# Partial word search - ElasticSearch 1.7.2

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I've been trying to build a search module for an application, using ElasticSearch. Below is the Index Structure I've constructed from sample code I read from other StackOverflow posts.

```
{
  "megacorp4":{
    "settings":{
      "analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
          "my_analyzer":{
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer":"my_ngram_tokenizer",
            "filter":[
              "my_ngram_filter"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter":{
          "my_ngram_filter":{
            "type":"edgeNGram",
            "min_gram":3,
            "max_gram":15
          }
        },
        "tokenizer":{
          "my_ngram_tokenizer":{
            "type":"edgeNGram",
            "min_gram":3,
            "max_gram":15
          }
        }
      },
      "mappings":{
        "employee":{
          "properties":{
            "about":{
              "type":"string",
              "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
            },
            "age":{
              "type":"long"
            },
            "first_name":{
              "type":"string"
            },
            "interests":{
              "type":"string",
              "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
            },
            "last_name":{
              "type":"string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below are the records I inserted to test the search functionality

```
[
  {
    "first_name":"John",
    "last_name":"Smith",
    "age":25,
    "about":"I love to go rock climbing",
    "interests":[
      "sports",
      "music"
    ]
  },
  {
    "first_name":"Douglas",
    "last_name":"Fir",
    "age":35,
    "about":"I like to build album climb cabinets",
    "interests":[
      "forestry",
      "music"
    ]
  },
  {
    "first_name":"Jane",
    "last_name":"Smith",
    "age":32,
    "about":"I like to collect rock albums",
    "interests":[
      "music"
    ]
  }
]
```

I ran a search on the 'about' column, both using API (through POSTMAN) and in the Python client as follows :

API Query:

```
localhost:9200/megacorp4/_search?q=climb
```

Python Query :

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from pprint import pprint
es = Elasticsearch()
res = es.search(index="megacorp4", body={"query": {"match": {'about':"climb"}}})
pprint(res)
```

I'm able to obtain only exact match, and I don't get the result with 'climbing' in the output. However when I replace 'climb' with 'climb*' in the query, I get 2 records with 'climb' and 'climbing'. I don't want to use '*' wildcard approach.

I've also tried using 'english', 'standard' & 'ngram' inbuilt analyzers, but nothing seemed to work.

In need of help to implement Search a key as Partial words in Full Text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this mapping instead:

DELETE test

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "my_ngram_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_ngram_filter": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 15
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "employee": {
      "properties": {
        "about": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "first_name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "interests": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "last_name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test/employee/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","age":25,"about":"I love to go rock climbing","interests":["sports","music"]}
{"index":{}}
{"first_name":"Douglas","last_name":"Fir","age":35,"about":"I like to build album climb cabinets","interests":["forestry","music"]}
{"index":{}}
{"first_name":"Jane","last_name":"Smith","age":32,"about":"I like to collect rock albums","interests":["music"]}

GET /test/_search?q=about:climb

GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "about:climb"
    }
  }
}

GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "about": "climb"
    }
  }
}
```

Two changes:

- you need another closing curly bracket for the `settings` part
- replace your custom tokenizer (which will not help you since you already have the edgeNGram filter) with another one, my suggestion is `standard` tokenizer

And for the `?q=climb` part, by default this searches the `_all` field which is analyzed with `standard` analyzer and not with your custom one.

So, the correct query is `localhost:9200/megacorp4/_search?q=about:climb`.

Comment: Used the mapping you provided, inserted the same 3 records, and ran the same search queries in POSTMAN and Python client, getting only the record with 'climb', still not getting the 'climbing' record :(

Comment: Tried `localhost:9200/megacorp4/_search?q=about:climb`, getting only the `climb` result and not the `climbing` result..

Comment: Did you delete the index?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the complete test code: index, mappings, settings, test data, test queries.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the index using the Python Client before recreating it with the mapping you provided
`es.indices.delete(index='megacorp4', ignore=[400, 404])`

Comment: Use the code I have provided. I have tested all of this with Marvel's [Sense dashboard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/dashboards.html#sense).

Comment: Deleted the index using the query `es.indices.delete(index='megacorp4', ignore=[400, 404])` once again, used your mapping, search, test data and test queries, still getting only the result `climb` :(

Comment: I know nothing about Python, this is the reason I gave you pure JSON code

Comment: My guess is you are doing something wrong in your Python code. What exactly, I don't know.

Comment: Ok, I avoided the Python approach, deleted the index using the command `curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/megacorp4/"`, then ran all the code you had given, still getting `climb` in the output.. I'm not sure what's wrong :(

Comment: Wow, let me test this in 1.7.2. The code I provided was tested in 1.7.1. There shouldn't be any differences, but just to be sure.

Comment: Tested in 1.7.2. The exact same code. Sorry, but it works for me.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried Andrei's approach and it works for me, too.

Comment: I tried it with a fresh install of ElasticSearch (1.7.2) in my personal PC, and the code you gave works ! Thanks @AndreiStefan ! I guess there's something going on when I delete an index, and create it again with the same name.. I maybe wrong, but I just don't see anything I did different, than recreating index with the same name :)

Comment: And Thanks @Val for trying it out !